# localstorage update property in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to update a property in localstorage.  I don't want to loop through and reset the whole thing.  Is this possible?

```
    var aR = [
    { "id": 1, "width": 500 },
    { "id": 2, "width": 400 }
]
localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(aR));

//  need to update property
localStorage['test'][1]['width'] = '720';
```

Comment: Nah, localStorage only works with string key/values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the opposite of stringify, `JSON.parse()`

```
    var arrayString = localStorage.getItem('test');
    var a = JSON.parse(arrayString);
    a[1]['width'] = '720';

// and do the same thing, stringify and store it back to local storage
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I'm still unclear.  if I update a[1] =1000 then I still have top remake the entire 'test' and put it all back into storage.  Can I just update the property or even the single object?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, because as Malk already mentioned localStorage only deals with key, value pairs as strings. So if you try to save an object as is, the default string representation of that object will be saved. For example, when you do `localStorage.setItem('test',aR)`, it will save without any error but when you try to retrieve it, you'll get the text representation of `aR` like this `[object Object],[object Object]` which is not useful as you won't be able to make out your values from that. So you have to convert that into a JSON string and save it again :)

Comment: if my answer works for you, feel free to up vote and accept :)

Comment: oops that 1st sentence came out wrong.. i mean to say NO you cannot update the property of any object in that array without parsing it again